# fosuserbundle and user in security token

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, serialization, fosuserbundle

I'm using fosuserbundle with a custom authentication provider and mongodb persisted user.
User class has a property persisted as a collection of reference to another mongodb collection, but this and other fields are not serialized in security token.
In another project of mine, the user as a plain old php object is correctly saved in and fetched from the token, so I don't understand if the problem is due to mongodb hydration overhaed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, in the token are persisted the user information that needs to be serialized. The fosuserbundle will serialize the properties:

```
 /**
 * Serializes the user.
 *
 * The serialized data have to contain the fields used by the equals method and the username.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->password,
        $this->salt,
        $this->usernameCanonical,
        $this->username,
        $this->expired,
        $this->locked,
        $this->credentialsExpired,
        $this->enabled,
        $this->id,
    ));
}
```

that are defined in the "serialize" method. If you want to serialize other properties you need to implement in your User class the methods serialize/unserialize. It's not a good practice, because when you retrieve the user from the token, normally he's refreshed. Have you implemented the method "refreshToken" in your UserProvider?

Comment: Indeed in my refreshUser method I took data from the old user and passed it along the nee instance but you are surely right and I overlooked serialize method in orginal fos user class.